# Good malware removal tool(s) for windows XP/Vista/7?

Tags: malware

The goal for this Wiki is to extablish a list of known good tools for cleaning up those pesky malware / virues that haunt windows clients. What tools do you like and what are their strengths and weaknesses?

I'll post my own favorite as an answer.

UPDATE: Not really sure why this was marked as off topic as desktops in the enterprise do get malware, and sometimes we have to clean them up.

Comment: Looks like SU already has this http://superuser.com/questions/5478/user-safe-malware-removal-tools

Comment: @Nixphoe: That's over 2 years old.  I suppose it could be updated, but ...

Comment: We don't do lists of products - this doesn't belong here or on SU.

Comment: Not really sure why this was marked as off topic as desktops in the enterprise do get malware?

Comment: @Alan: One doesn't "clean up" compromised machines. You reinstall them from known-good media. Anything less is risking that a persistent malicious program will remain.

Comment: Sometimes you do... depends on the situation doesnt it? In this reinstalling the OS was not an option. I ended up using malware bytes to clean it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ultimate Boot CD for Windows](http://www.ubcd4win.com/) has about 12 different tools for virus & malware removal.  The best part of using this boot CD is that it is out-of-band and therefore no viruses on the system can interfere with scanning and removal.  You can also install it to a bootable USB stick and keep the definitions updated.

Comment: I'll give you the answered for effort - despite the fact it only lasted 5 mins.

Answer (score 5):

I tend to find a Windows installation CD to be the best tool for removing malware. Backup the system. Format the system. Reinstall the system. Restore the backup. Fixes them EVERY time.

Comment: Nuke from orbit. That's the only professional method, IMHO.